# Display div using for loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I have a HTML structure:

```
<div class="ttl">
   <div class="ttlpadding">
      <div class="item"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My aim is to display 10 images inside .item which will be contained in .ttlpadding which will be contained in .ttl.
So, there will be individual .ttl for each individual .item and its corresponding individual image.

My JQuery code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       $(".item").append("<a href='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +"' ><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a>");
}
```

Currently, all the the ten images are getting contained inside a single ".item" and hence a single ".ttl". I've tried many variations but can't figure out the correct way.

Comment: 'I want to run a for loop creating 10 divs of "ttl" which will be having an image inside ".item"' doesn't seem to make sense. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: It should 10 different ttl divs in the page having individual 10 images.
Currently, its showing all the 10 images(ie, 10 item divs) in a single ttl div.

Comment: inside your loop you are selecting every element on the page with class `item` and then appending a link and image. Nowhere are you making the `ttl` divs, or selecting which one you want the image added to

Comment: @JackB.: I've edited the question. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.ttl').first().parent().append(
"<div class="ttl">
   <div class="ttlpadding">
      <div class="item">" + 

"<a href='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +"' ><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a>" +
"</div>
   </div>
</div>"
);
```

This selects .ttl (the first one), goes to it's parent, and adds the necessary divs and image code.

Answer (score 1):

Your ten items are inside the single "ttl" because that's where you are attaching them to
 `$(".item").append........`

You need to attach them to a higher element in the hierarchy.

Comment: I actually think I like this answer the best, because it goes to the root of the problem instead of trying to solve the issues with the code. User doesn't really understand DOM hierarchy yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your appending to the inner div. Use jquery `clone` function to duplicate the outer ttl div. The doc of the clone function has an example explaining what you want. http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Basically it would look like this:

```
var clone = $('.ttl').clone().filter('.item').append(your_html_from_your_example);
```

You still need to put this new clone object into your DOM. Probably append to the parent of ttl:

```
$('.ttl').parent().append(clone);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble creating the wanted html structure, do it the old fashion way :

```
var html='';

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    html += '<div class="ttl">';
    html +=  '<div class="ttlpadding">';
    html +=   '<div class="item">';
    html +=    '<a href="' + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +'" >';
    html +=     '<img src="' + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +'" />';
    html +=    '</a>';
    html +=   '</div>';
    html +=  '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
}
$("element").append(html);
```

Comment: lol mine was the halfway point to this. Yeah. It's better to understand what you're doing than to do something better and not know how to fix it when it breaks.

Comment: Yeah, it's not very pretty with lots of jQuery functions and stuff, but it is easy to understand, and a good place to start when you're not quite sure how to build the wanted structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var original=$(".ttl")[0];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var el=original.cloneNode(true);
  el.firstChild.firstChild.innerHTML="<a href='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +"' ><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a>";
  document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're appending your images to class "item" which is inside your "ttl". If you want ten items of class "ttl" you'll need to append to the parent class of "ttl". 
For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Javascript/JQuery

```
htmlToAppend = "
  <div class="ttl">
     <div class="ttlpadding">
         <div class="item"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
 "; //may not be valid javascript but it should give you the right idea.

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   $(htmlToAppend).filter(".item").append("<a href='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +"' ><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a>");
   $(".container").append(htmlToAppend);
}
```

Or what everyone else said. Pick the one you like best.

Comment: This will append the link after all the divs close.

Comment: Yes you're right, I forgot to filter on "item". I've updated the code.